# How do I use a different column to search within a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html

I use a JavaScript function to filter out lines of a table. However, whenever I input anything all table rows disappear. It seems to be looking for the words I search in the wrong column. How can I make the function look in the column "doorName"?

The search function:

```
function SearchFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("doorTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "th" tags of the table:

```
<table class="table" id="doorTable" style="color:white">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="CheckAll" onclick="UnCheckAll()"/>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CloseRight)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OpenRight)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.doorName)
            </th>
```

The "td" tags of the table:

```
<tr id="ScaleLine">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="boxCheck" class="doorNameBoxes" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.doorName)>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CloseRight)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OpenRight)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.doorName)
                </td>
```

I want to search within the column "doorName".

Comment: `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` gets the first `td` (column) in each `tr`. Knowing that, replace `0` with the index of column with "doorName"

Comment: @HereticMonkey That works, thank you!